# Передача функции с аргументами в качестве функции

Tags: javascript, коллекции, параметры

Как передать функцию с аргументами в качестве аргумента (см. переменную result), причем так, чтобы сначала вызвалась функция query, затем функция filterIn, а затем select и в итоге результат вернулся в виде массива объектов (коллекции)?

Ведь если сейчас просто запустить, то вызовется сначала select, потом filterIn и уже потом query

```
var lib = {
    query: query,
    select: select,
    filterIn: filterIn
};

function query(collection) {
    //Сюда получаем
}

function select() {
    //Код для выборки только нужных ключей коллекции
}

function filterIn(property, values) {
    //Код для фильтрации коллекции
}

var people = [
    {
        name: 'Андрей',
        gender: 'Мужской',
        email: 'andrey@site.ru',
    },
    {
        name: 'Николай',
        gender: 'Мужской',
        email: 'halo@site.ru',
    }
]

var result = lib.query(
    people,
    lib.select('name', 'gender'),
    lib.filterIn('name', ['Андрей', 'Николай'])
);
```

Причем реализацию переменной result и коллекции редактировать нельзя, все остальное можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Речь не о запуске функци (его изменить невозможно), а о порядке применения операций к массиву. Функции `select` и `filterIn` должны возвращать другие функции, которые и будут в нужном порядке вызываться в `query`:

```js
var lib = {
    query: query,
    select: select,
    filterIn: filterIn
};

function query(arr, ...fs) {
    console.log('query');

    for (var q=fs.length; q--; ) {
      arr = fs[q](arr)
    }
    
    return arr;
}

function select(...fields) {
    return function (arr) {
        console.log('select');
        
        return arr.map(x => {
          var res = {};
          for (var f of fields) res[f] = x[f];
          return res;
        });
    }
}

function filterIn(property, values) {
    return function (arr) {
        console.log('filterIn');
        
        return arr.filter(x => ~values.indexOf(x[property]));
    }
}

var people = [
    {
        name: 'Андрей',
        gender: 'Мужской',
        email: 'andrey@site.ru',
    },
    {
        name: 'Николай',
        gender: 'Мужской',
        email: 'halo@site.ru',
    }
]

var result = lib.query(
    people,
    lib.select('name', 'gender'),
    lib.filterIn('name', ['Андрей', 'Николай'])
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 0):

Возвращаемые данные из одной функции надо передавать в другую, и так по цепочке.

`select(filter(query(queryArgs), filterArgs), selectArgs);`

Comment: просили же вызов query не менять...